# Why do I get differend results from --trace-opt/--trace-deopt and %GetOptimizationStatus V8's API call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

This is the output of `v8 --module --trace-opt index.js`. You can see that optimization of functions `commonRandom and commonRandomJS` was completed.

```
...
[completed optimizing 0x2b0e0824a769 <JSFunction commonRandom (sfi = 0x2b0e081d3985)> (target TURBOFAN)]
...
[completed optimizing 0x2b0e0824a789 <JSFunction commonRandomJS (sfi = 0x2b0e081d39b9)> (target TURBOFAN)]
...
```

This is the output of `v8 --module --trace-deopt index.js`. You can see that functions `commonRandom and commonRandomJS` were not deopted.

```
[bailout (kind: deopt-soft, reason: Insufficient type feedback for compare operation): begin. deoptimizing 0x3907082827f9 <JSFunction randomMatrix (sfi = 0x3907081d39ed)>, opt id 0, bytecode offset 167, deopt exit 35, FP to SP delta 208, caller SP 0x7ffee6068410, pc 0x39070004611c]
[bailout (kind: deopt-soft, reason: Insufficient type feedback for compare operation): begin. deoptimizing 0x39070824a839 <JSFunction randomMatrix (sfi = 0x3907081d39ed)>, opt id 2, bytecode offset 249, deopt exit 28, FP to SP delta 208, caller SP 0x7ffee6068410, pc 0x390700047265]
[bailout (kind: deopt-soft, reason: Insufficient type feedback for unary operation): begin. deoptimizing 0x39070824a839 <JSFunction randomMatrix (sfi = 0x3907081d39ed)>, opt id 3, bytecode offset 349, deopt exit 23, FP to SP delta 264, caller SP 0x7ffee6068410, pc 0x390700047d5b]
```

I've implemented my own tracing script according to https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/207f489fc5df0cab30b9cde373181c0242c0874c/src/runtime/runtime.h#L897 `%GetOptimizationStatus` current implementation and used the same number of iterations as with `--trace-opt/--trace-deopt` flags. Howether, the `kTurboFanned` flag is `0`, but `kOptimized and kMaglevved` are both `1s`. Why is it so? What does `kTurbofanned`, `kOptimized` and `kMaglevved` flags mean then?

**Verions:**
`V8 version 9.9.67`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 is, as it has always been, under active development. To interpret 9.9.67's `%GetOptimizationStatus` output, refer to the correct version of runtime.h: `https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/9.9.67/src/runtime/runtime.h`.

"Maglev" is a new compiler, still under development, and slotting in between Sparkplug and Turbofan. Version 9.9.x didn't have it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your response, did not spot the difference between version tags!
And last mini-question: "kOptimized" and "kTurboFanned" are the same thing for now (since there is no other optimizing compiler)? Or "kOptimized" also includes the optimizations done on the interpreter/baseline compiler level?

Comment: @KamilRizatdinov Should be the same for now; will likely get more complicated in the future.